# How to avoid automatic adding of /usr/lib64 in Qt pro file

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, libraries

I have a Qt project. I can add some libraries using the commands like:

`LIBS += -lopencv_core`

They work perfectly for me. However, if I check the output, I have there other libraries, too. For example `/usr/lib64`, without mentioning this anywhere in the project. How can I avoid that addition?

Answer (score 1):

You can explicity remove these paths. For example, I use that to remove all standard path (lib and includes) :

```
unix {
            LIBS -= -L/usr/lib/
            LIBS -= -L/usr/lib64/
            LIBS -= -L/usr/lib
            LIBS -= -L/usr/lib64
            INCLUDEPATH -= /usr/include/
            INCLUDEPATH -= /usr/include
        }
```